# XPages JSON service not returning all records when using search

Tags: json, fullcalendar, xpages, lotus-notes

I am display data in a fullcalendar via a JSON service (calling a Lotus Notes database). If I do a simple call, all the data is returned - which is good but there are over 3000 documents, so this slows the calendar response. When I try and reduce the number of records being returned via a search such as

```
" FIELD EV_StartTime >= 01-10-2018 AND FIELD EV_EndTime <= 01-06-2019";
```

or 
    " FIELD EV_Category = Watches "
then only 33 records are returned (1095 expected)

I have the count field set to 1000 as suggested by others but this has made no difference (tho it does when I have no search criteria).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? If you add such a filter, you'd expect a lower result count - so why should that be wrong?

Comment: "then only 33 records are returned"...how many did you expect? How many have you got which meet your filter criteria? Is that a SQL where clause you've shown us? What database are you using? Maybe your database doesn't like the date format or is interpreting it as dd-mm-yyyy instead of mm-dd-yyyy (or the opposite) - maybe use something unambiguous such as yyyy-mm-dd. So many possibilities, none of which appear to have anything to do with fullCalendar or JSON, and probably not xpages either.

Comment: A years worth, as there are 3 records per day this would be 1095 records.

Comment: Only 33 of the 1095 were returned. The JSON is calling a Notes database. The query works in a view, however have tried on a text field as well i.e FIELD EV_Category = Watchs and it still only returns 33 records

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a this issue, in the Rest Service control there is a property called searchMaxDocs which requires a value, when doing a search, otherwise it appears to default to a smallish value